# Deploying Symfony2 app to ec2 using Capifony

Tags: amazon-ec2, capistrano, symfony

I'm attempting to deploy my symfony2 app to my ec2 instance. I have my deploy.rb file configured and I'm able to initialize the server directory using cap deploy:setup. However, when I run cap deploy I get this error: `failed "sh -c 'cd /var/www/html/capifonytest/releases/20110920052019 && php app/console cache:warmup --env=prod'" on xxx.xx.xxx.xx`. Here's my deploy.rb file:

```
set :application, "capifonytest"

default_run_options[:pty] = true
set :scm, :git

set :deploy_to, "/var/www/html/#{application}"

set :repository, "git@github.com:myname/myrepo.git"
set :branch, "master"
set :ssh_options, { :forward_agent => true }

set :user, "ec2-user"
set :domain, "xxx.xx.xxx.xx"
ssh_options[:keys] = [File.join(ENV["AWS_HOME"], "tsmith.pem")]

role :web,        domain                         # Your HTTP server, Apache/etc
role :app,        domain                         # This may be the same as your `Web` server
role :db,         domain, :primary => true       # This is where Rails migrations will run

set :use_sudo, true
set  :keep_releases,  3
```

Does anyone know of a good tutorial/resource for deploying a symfony2 app to a ec2 instance or using capifony/capistrano to do so? Also, any tips or tricks to get symfony2 working on an ec2 instance would be greatly appropriated. I'm running the amazon linux ami 64bit, which I believe is based on centos.

---

Here's a more detailed snippet of the output:

> servers: ["107.20.247.96"]
>       [107.20.247.96] executing command
>    ** [out :: 107.20.247.96] find: `/var/www/html/capifonytest/releases/2011092118<br />
>   2846/web/css': No such file or directory<br />
>    ** [out :: 107.20.247.96] find:`/var/www/html/capifonytest/releases/2011092118
>   2846/web/images': No such file or directory
>    ** [out :: 107.20.247.96] find: `/var/www/html/capifonytest/releases/2011092118<br />
>   2846/web/js': No such file or directory<br />
>       command finished in 358ms<br />
>       triggering after callbacks for`deploy:finalize_update'
>     * executing `symfony:cache:warmup'
>     * executing "cd /var/www/html/capifonytest/releases/20110921182846 && php app/
>   console cache:warmup --env=prod"
>       servers: ["107.20.247.96"]
>       [107.20.247.96] executing command
>    ** [out :: 107.20.247.96] PHP Warning:  require_once(/var/www/html/capifonytest
>   /releases/20110921182846/app/../vendor/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Locale/Reso
>   urces/stubs/functions.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in
>   /var/www/html/capifonytest/releases/20110921182846/app/autoload.php on line 25
>    ** [out :: 107.20.247.96] PHP Fatal error:  require_once(): Failed opening requ
>   ired '/var/www/html/capifonytest/releases/20110921182846/app/../vendor/symfony/s
>   rc/Symfony/Component/Locale/Resources/stubs/functions.php' (include_path='.:/usr
>   /share/pear:/usr/share/php') in /var/www/html/capifonytest/releases/201109211828
>   46/app/autoload.php on line 25
>       command finished in 302ms
>   *** [deploy:update_code] rolling back
>     * executing "rm -rf /var/www/html/capifonytest/releases/20110921182846; true"
>       servers: ["107.20.247.96"]
>       [107.20.247.96] executing command
>       command finished in 280ms
>   failed: "sh -c 'cd /var/www/html/capifonytest/releases/20110921182846 && php app
>   /console cache:warmup --env=prod'" on 107.20.247.96

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A little late, but...

If you recursively `chown` and `chgrp` your deploy directory (in your case `/var/www/html/#{application}`) with the deploy user, capifony should be able to clear the caches.  In other words:

```
sudo chown -R ec2-user /var/www/html/#{application}
sudo chgrp -R ec2-user /var/www/html/#{application}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `cache` and `logs` folders aren't most likely writable. Check section `Setting up Permissions` in [Symfony2 book](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/installation.html) for more information how to set it up in various environments.